# Fetching e-mails into Redmine via IMAP

Tags: logging, imap, redmine

I'm trying to fetch e-mails into Redmine via IMAP.

The e-mails I'm generating look like this:

```
FooBar Ltd 
123456
http://example.com/Foobar-Ltd-123456.html

Project: backend
Tracker: Dataerror

Beschreibung:
This is the description

===========================
CLIENT_IP: 192.168.1.215
HTTP_USER_AGENT: mozilla/asdfjköl
```

I try to fetch them into Redmine via this command:

```
rake -f /var/www/projects/redmine/Rakefile redmine:email:receive_imap \
RAILS_ENV="production" host=example.com port=993 ssl=true username=redmine \
password=1234 project=myproject tracker=other \
allow_override=project,tracker,category,priority \
move_on_success=read move_on_failure=failed
```

But the e-mails get moved into the failed folder.

I had this setup running some time ago with a different e-mail generator but pretty much the same template, and I can't figure out why it's not working. The permissions seem to be OK too.

In order to further debug this issue, I need some logfiles. Are there any logfiles written by this command? Or are there any other suggestions to solve this issue?

My environment:

```
danilo@jabba:/var/www/projects/redmine$
RAILS_ENV=production script/about
About your application's environment
Ruby version              1.8.7 (i486-linux)
RubyGems version          1.3.5
Rack version              1.0
Rails version             2.3.5
Active Record version     2.3.5
Active Resource version   2.3.5
Action Mailer version     2.3.5
Active Support version    2.3.5
Application root          /var/www/projects/redmine
Environment               production
Database adapter          mysql
Database schema version   20100819172912
```

Comment: If something interesting shows up with `rake --trace`, please post it.

Comment: @harrymc: Nothing special, no errors. The fetching works without problems, it's just the parsing that seems to fail. And there is no output about the reasons for the failing.

Comment: You could try taking off values from allow_override. IMO this is the only parameter that can cause email to fail.

Comment: And have you looked at production.log?

Comment: @harrymc: Yes I have, nothing in there about IMAP. And even when removing the overrides parameter entirely, they all fail.

Answer (score 2):

From [rake redmine:email:receive_imap does not receive mails](http://www.redmine.org/boards/2/topics/4800) :

> In the model issue.rb there is a code
>
> `validates_presence_of :subject,
>   :description, :priority, :project,
>   :tracker, :author, :status`
>
> which says that priority is mandatory
>   field. So i cannot create issue without
>   receiving the value for priority
>   parameter.

I am not a user of rake and do not have your environment, but you could check if you have some validation rule somewhere that causes email to fail. From your example, you only have project and tracker in the email, so requiring more will cause it to fail.

Comment: No I tried many combinations, with or without parameters. I also tried providing a default priority value. No change.

Comment: The article mentioned rules that are built-into the rake environment and are found in files with an ".rb" suffix. Try to search for all "*.rb" files on your computer. If you find some, see if something in their content rings a bell, especially  a "validates_presence_of :" line.

Comment: Well, Redmine documents their required and optional values. And even when using exactly the rake commands from their examples, it does not work.

Comment: It may work in their environment, with their ".rb" file.

Answer (score 2):

You could also try `unknown_user=accept no-permission-check=1` based on: http://www.redmine.org/projects/redmine/wiki/RedmineReceivingEmails#Enabling-unknown-users-to-create-issues-by-email

For more help, see your Redmine: [lib/tasks/email.rake](https://github.com/redmine/redmine/blob/master/lib/tasks/email.rake) and lib/redmine/imap.rb

Answer (score 1):

After quite a lot of finagling, I figured out that in my case, the problem was that my project name had a space in it. I was quoting the name (project="My Project"), but the code just silently failed. When I replaced the project name with the fixed single-token name (project="my_project"). It worked.

The most frustrating thing for me was not having sufficient diagnostic feedback.